# UnboundLocalError at /products/search/ local variable 'query' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have this problem

> UnboundLocalError at /products/search local variable 'query' referenced before assignment

/on this code help out, am searching a product using title and category

```
def search(request):
    try:
        q = request.GET.get('q', '')
    except:
        q = False
    if q:
        query = q

    product_queryset = Product.objects.filter(
        Q(name__icontains=q)|
        Q(description__icontains=q)
    )
    category_queryset = Category.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=q)|
        Q(description__icontains=q)
    )
    results = list(chain(product_queryset,category_queryset))
    context = {
        'query':query,
        'product_queryset':product_queryset,
        'category_queryset':category_queryset,
        'results':results,
    }

    return render(request,"products/search.html", context)
```

Comment: If `q` is False-y, you don't define the variable `query`.

Comment: how to do that help

Comment: I don't know, it depends on what you want to do if `q` is empty.

Comment: if it empty returns empty message

Answer (score 0):

Like Selcuk said, you're not defining `query` if `q` is None/False. Try:

```
def search(request):
    try:
        q = request.GET.get('q', '')
    except:
        q = False
    if q:
        query = q
    else:
        query = None

    product_queryset = Product.objects.filter(
        Q(name__icontains=q)|
        Q(description__icontains=q)
    )
    category_queryset = Category.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=q)|
        Q(description__icontains=q)
    )
    results = list(chain(product_queryset,category_queryset))
    context = {
        'query':query,
        'product_queryset':product_queryset,
        'category_queryset':category_queryset,
        'results':results,
    }

    return render(request,"products/search.html", context)
```

We're not sure what `query` is supposed to be or how you're using it though. Setting it to None should fix the UnboundLocalError.

I also don't see any reason that you need to wrap `q = request.GET.get('q', '')` in a try/except block. `get` will return '' if `q` isn't defined. You could simplify the code to be:

```
def search(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q', '')

    product_queryset = Product.objects.filter(
        Q(name__icontains=q)|
        Q(description__icontains=q)
    )
    category_queryset = Category.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=q)|
        Q(description__icontains=q)
    )
    results = list(chain(product_queryset,category_queryset))
    context = {
        'query': q,
        'product_queryset':product_queryset,
        'category_queryset':category_queryset,
        'results':results,
    }

    return render(request,"products/search.html", context)
```

template form

```
    <form method="get" action="{% url 'products:search' %}">
        <button class="flex-c-m trans-04">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-search"></i>
        </button>
        <input class="plh3" type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="q">
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the first code with try and except the search function prints all the products insteady of the asked one

Comment: Same applies to the second option just shows the list of all products

Comment: Are you sure `q` is in request.GET?

Comment: Yeah it is, and it was working fine until when i upgraded to python 3.7

Comment: Try taking a closer look at what's actually in `q`. Maybe `print(q)` to verify it looks like what you expect. I'd also try printing the two querysets independently to see what they look like.

Comment: I have tested it in a different form works fine something is wrong with the html form in the template i have updated the question take a look

Comment: I have seen the problem it is with the name ' q' it is duplicate

Comment: Yup. I just edited the template to remove the duplicate "name" param you had there. Working now?